# Configuring Magento Enterprise to Print UPS Return Labels

Tags: shipping, ups, enterprise-rma

I've been working to get the Enterprise_Rma module configured to print return labels using UPS.

I've run into a handful of somewhat odd hiccups thus far.

- The *Mode* parameter doesn't have to be set to *Live* in order to be in Live mode.  It seems to only affect whether or not `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` is used in the cURL request.
- I've had to flip *UPS Type* back and forth a bit between *United Parcel Service* and *United Parcel Service XML* in order to get rates to show up when creating a shipping label.  At first, it didn't show any rates when using the latter.

But the main question I have right now is how to properly change the ShipAccept and ShipConfirm API endpoint URLs from their default sandbox (might also be called Customer Integration Environment by UPS) values to the production values.

The sandbox values are:

```
'ShipConfirm' => 'https://wwwcie.ups.com/ups.app/xml/ShipConfirm',
'ShipAccept'  => 'https://wwwcie.ups.com/ups.app/xml/ShipAccept',
```

And the production values need to be:

```
'ShipConfirm' => 'https://onlinetools.ups.com/ups.app/xml/ShipConfirm',
'ShipAccept'  => 'https://onlinetools.ups.com/ups.app/xml/ShipAccept',
```

The *ShipConfirm* endpoint can be configured with the config path `carriers/ups/url` but the *ShipAccept* doesn't seem possible to change in any way other than modifying `Mage_Usa_Model_Shipping_Carrier_Ups` directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Mage_Usa carrier models are half-baked.. I suggest core *replacement* in app/code/local/Mage/Usa/... E.g. I replaced their protected properties with:

```
protected $_apiUrls = array(
    self::DEVELOPMENT => array(
        'ShipConfirm' => 'https://wwwcie.ups.com/ups.app/xml/ShipConfirm',
        'ShipAccept'  => 'https://wwwcie.ups.com/ups.app/xml/ShipAccept',
        'XAV'  => 'https://wwwcie.ups.com/ups.app/xml/XAV',  // Only works for NY or CA addresses
        'Void'  => 'https://wwwcie.ups.com/ups.app/xml/Void',
    ),
    self::PRODUCTION => array(
        'ShipConfirm' => 'https://onlinetools.ups.com/ups.app/xml/ShipConfirm',
        'ShipAccept'  => 'https://onlinetools.ups.com/ups.app/xml/ShipAccept',
        'XAV'  => 'https://onlinetools.ups.com/ups.app/xml/XAV',
        'Void'  => 'https://onlinetools.ups.com/ups.app/xml/Void',
    )
);
```

Then change the code to fetch the URL like:

```
$url = $this->_apiUrls[(int)$this->getConfigFlag(self::IS_PRODUCTION)]['ShipConfirm'];
```

Comment: Gotcha.  Wow, crazy they'd be so half baked.  Why local code pool replacement instead of a class rewrite though?

Comment: A class rewrite might confuse others, especially if the site is updated to a newer version that "finishes the baking". If you'd rather do a class rewrite, make sure you provide adequate commenting.

Comment: Personally, I went for a rewrite.  I think the customization footprint is a lot smaller than a local code pool class.

Comment: I used class rewrite because I made (and it is likely the more you use it that you will make) changes that would break backwards compatibility. If it isn't compatible with the parent class then why override? E.g. there are lots of PHP Notices logged that I prefer to fix (noisy logs make problems harder to spot), and I need to take advantage of other API features that Magento doesn't use or are hard-coded.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to Colin's suggestion to use a local code pool override, I went with a class rewrite.  The rewrite is pretty clean as you can overload the two methods in question pretty neatly, keeping the parent calls in tact.

```
class Clean_Shipping_Model_Usa_Shipping_Carrier_Ups extends Mage_Usa_Model_Shipping_Carrier_Ups
{
    protected function _setEndpointUrls()
    {
        if (Mage::helper('cleanship')->isUpsApiInProductionMode()) {
            $this->_defaultUrls = array(
                'ShipConfirm' => 'https://onlinetools.ups.com/ups.app/xml/ShipConfirm',
                'ShipAccept'  => 'https://onlinetools.ups.com/ups.app/xml/ShipAccept',
            );
        }

        return $this;
    }

    protected function _doShipmentRequest(Varien_Object $request)
    {
        $this->_setEndpointUrls();
        return parent::_doShipmentRequest($request);
    }

    protected function _sendShipmentAcceptRequest(SimpleXMLElement $shipmentConfirmResponse)
    {
        $this->_setEndpointUrls();
        return parent::_sendShipmentAcceptRequest($shipmentConfirmResponse);
    }
}
```